# Do I need an Airport transit visa /travelling through Greece?

Tags: schengen-visas, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, greece, aegean-airlines

I am a pakistani passport holder. I am travelling from UK to Saudi via Aegean airlines, having 50 mins stay/lay over at the Athens airport.
It’s a direct flight means onward flight is in the same ticket.

Do i need a transit visa please someone can guide me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do (unless you fall under the list of exceptions - a UK visa isn't one of them). See [the EU's list of countries whose nationals must have an airport transit visa](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/document/download/b4c96db2-f9ff-4fba-8106-89a52c9c4121_en?filename=annex_7a_atv_common_list_en.pdf) and their page on [who must apply for a Schengen visa](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy/who-must-apply-schengen-visa_en).

Comment: The site you've linked to is notorious here for having out of date information.  It's better to link to an official source.

Comment: @phoog It's correct though

Comment: @Crazydre which is why I didn't say it's incorrect.  However, we should not lend credibility to a source that doesn't deserve it when official sources are available.  People often mistake that site for an official source, which could also lead to misinformation.  The page linked in this answer does not reflect the current "List of third countries whose nationals are required to be in possession of an airport transit visa when passing through the international 
transit area of airports situated on the territory of one/some Member States," for example.

Comment: @phoog Added an official source.

Comment: Yes but apart from the list of countries what i ask is that I’m not exiting the international transit area of the Athens airport because I’m not changing the aeroplane , it’s 50 minute of stay I don’t think we are even changing the terminal .

Comment: @MrWazir Doesn't matter - Pakistanis require an airport transit visa _even_ if you're staying in the international transit area.